# System.ArgumentException: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set

Tags: c#, .net, forms, crystal-reports

I'm new to windows programming, I have created an application to run on 64bit machine. The application has one crystal report as well. The application is perfectly working on my machine, but when I try to install it on some other machine, it throws the below error. I have installed Crystal report runtime 13 on the destination PC in order to make it work, without any success.
Below is the error I'm getting in while opening the page.

```
see the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.CheckNoDataSource()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Insert(Int32 index, Object item)
   at TO_Automation.MovedItems.FillList()
   at TO_Automation.MovedItems.MovedItems_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
TO Automation
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Whites/TOA/TO%20Automation.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
MaterialSkin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Whites/TOA/MaterialSkin.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Version: 13.0.12.1494
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Version: 13.0.12.1494
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Shared/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

What can be the reason for this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about Crystal Reports. The problem is in `FillList` method in `MovedItems`. The error means that you can't Insert items to ComboBox after you set DataSource property. Try add item to your data source.